# Authorization error in Google Cloud Speech

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Cloud Speech for streaming speech recognition, but I am getting the following authorization error:

```
AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7fb935b86da0>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 78, in __call__
    context, _AuthMetadataPluginCallback(callback_state, callback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 86, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 73, in _get_authorization_headers
    self._request, context.method_name, context.service_url, headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 360, in refresh
    assertion = self._make_authorization_grant_assertion()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 354, in _make_authorization_grant_assertion
    token = jwt.encode(self._signer, payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/jwt.py", line 112, in encode
    signature = signer.sign(signing_input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/crypt/_cryptography_rsa.py", line 112, in sign
    return self._key.sign(message, _PADDING, _SHA256)
AttributeError: '_RSAPrivateKey' object has no attribute 'sign'
```

Strangely enough, we have several servers (all on Ubuntu 16.04), and on the other server everything works without any errors.
Credentials for these servers are identical, versions of packages (google-api-core == 1.23.0, google-auth == 1.23.0, google-cloud-speech == 1.0.0, googleapis-common-protos == 1.52.0) also identical, same with the code, but one server has this error, and the other does not.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Some tips: 1) Edit your question and include your code. 2) One of your method/function calls failed. This created a null object which results in the error `_RSAPrivateKey' object has no attribute 'sign`. 3) Use try/except in your code to catch and handle errors(exceptions).

Comment: Which credential do you use? Your user account? A service account? Can you share the python code that call the API to reproduce it on our side?

Comment: Can you explain which kind of credentials are you using and share your code?